# GWT RequestFactory: inheriting interfaces into a RequestContext

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I have my OrganizationRequestContext interface, which works great:

```
@Service(OrganizationDAO.class)
public interface OrganizationRequestContext extends RequestContext
{
    Request<OrganizationProxy> findOrganization(Long id);

    InstanceRequest<OrganizationProxy, Void> persist();
    InstanceRequest<OrganizationProxy, Void> remove();
}
```

Now I want to take those last two functions and put them in a `PersistentRequestContext` of my own design so that I can treat all of my RequestContexts the same in my client code:

```
public interface PersistableRequestContext<T extends BaseProxy>
{
    InstanceRequest<T, Void> persist();
    InstanceRequest<T, Void> remove();
}
```

...

```
@Service(OrganizationDAO.class)
public interface OrganizationRequestContext extends RequestContext, PersistentRequestContext<OrganizationProxy>
{
    Request<OrganizationProxy> findOrganization(Long id);
}
```

But this fails validation: the server complains that

```
[ERROR] com.activegrade.shared.data.PersistableRequestContext is not a RequestContext
```

If I make PersistableRequestContext extend RequestContext, then the server complains that it is not linked to any particular DAO service.

Is there any way to extend a common interface besides `RequestContext` in my various RequestContext interfaces?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you've hit on a limit in the RequestContext code generator. Your best bet may be to create an issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list

Comment: Issue created: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6035

Comment: Why didn't you put a @Service annotation to the PersistableRequestContext as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in GWT 2.4.  Thanks Google!

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6035